# XAML code won't compile

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Please can someone be of help. Below is my XAML code that won't compile

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLCalendar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLCalendar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">

            <!-- Create a Calendar that displays dates through 
            Januarary 31, 2015 and has dates that are not selectable. -->

            <Calendar Margin = "20" SelectionMode = "MultipleRange"   
            IsTodayHighlighted = "false"  
            DisplayDate = "1/1/2015" 
            DisplayDateEnd = "1/31/2015" 
            SelectedDatesChanged = "Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" 
            xmlns:sys = "clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib">

                <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
                    <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/2/2015" End = "1/4/2015"/>
                    <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/9/2015" End = "1/9/2015"/>
                    <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/16/2015" End = "1/16/2015"/>
                    <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/23/2015" End = "1/25/2015"/>
                    <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/30/2015" End = "1/30/2015"/>
                </Calendar.BlackoutDates>

                <Calendar.SelectedDates>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/5/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/12/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/14/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/13/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/15/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>1/27/2015</sys:DateTime>
                    <sys:DateTime>4/2/2015</sys:DateTime>
                </Calendar.SelectedDates>

            </Calendar>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Below is the c# partial class behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace XAMLCalendar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var calendar = sender as Calendar;

            // ... See if a date is selected. 

            if (calendar.SelectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                // ... Display SelectedDate in Title. 
                DateTime date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
                this.Title = date.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error messages I get

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error  Unknown build error, ''clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib' mapping URI is not valid. Line 6 Position 9.' XAMLCalendar C:\Users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XAMLCalendar\XAMLCalendar\MainWindow.xaml line 6
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error  The URI "clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib" is not a valid namespace identifier. XAMLCalendar C:\Users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XAMLCalendar\XAMLCalendar\MainWindow.xaml line 20
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error  The name "DateTime" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib". XAMLCalendar C:\Users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XAMLCalendar\XAMLCalendar\MainWindow.xaml  line 31
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error  The name "DateTime" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib". XAMLCalendar C:\Users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XAMLCalendar\XAMLCalendar\MainWindow.xaml  line 32

........and the same errors as the one directly above, up to line 37

Please can someone tell me why it won't compile. I've tried adding mscorlib reference to my project, but it won't let me. Saying "This component is already automatically referenced by the build system"

Also there's a wriggle line under xmlns:sys  in the Calender element in the XAML above. When I hover my mouse over it, the intellisense says "The URI "clr-namespace:System;assembly =mscorlib" is not a valid namespace identifier

Cheers. Am using Microsoft visual studio 2017 community

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal Cheers mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the extra whitespace in namespace declaration.

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLCalendar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLCalendar"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">

        <!-- Create a Calendar that displays dates through 
        Januarary 31, 2015 and has dates that are not selectable. -->

        <Calendar Margin = "20" SelectionMode = "MultipleRange"   
        IsTodayHighlighted = "false"  
        DisplayDate = "1/1/2015" 
        DisplayDateEnd = "1/31/2015" 
        SelectedDatesChanged = "Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" 
        xmlns:sys = "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

            <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
                <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/2/2015" End = "1/4/2015"/>
                <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/9/2015" End = "1/9/2015"/>
                <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/16/2015" End = "1/16/2015"/>
                <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/23/2015" End = "1/25/2015"/>
                <CalendarDateRange Start = "1/30/2015" End = "1/30/2015"/>
            </Calendar.BlackoutDates>

            <Calendar.SelectedDates>
                <sys:DateTime>1/5/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/12/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/14/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/13/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/15/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>1/27/2015</sys:DateTime>
                <sys:DateTime>4/2/2015</sys:DateTime>
            </Calendar.SelectedDates>

        </Calendar>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: To make this clear there was a space before =mscorlib

Comment: @apc, Thank you! I just accidentally removed the comment above the code.

Comment: @apc Cheers mate. Sorted. Should be assembly=. Shouldn't be anything between assembly and the equal sign

Comment: @Yevgeniy Thanks for your concern